# An Injective function of n variables which is not surjective.

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

Prove that f:R^n to R^n defined by f(x)=x(|x|^2)is Injective not surjective. Injective is easy to prove. f(x)=f(y) implies x|x|^2=y|y|^2 hence taking norms we get |x|^3=|y|^3 which gives |x|=|y|. Substituting in the above equation we get x=y. How to prove f is not surjective? The jacobian at origin vanishes. Will it be of any help to prove the result?? Please help.

Comment: Who says it's not surjective?

Comment: Actually, $x=f\left(\frac{x}{|x|^{2/3}}\right)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ given by $x\mapsto x|x|^2$ is surjective. Intuitively, $x|x|^2$ is just a version of $x$ scaled by the scalar factor of $|x|^2$, so that $x|x|^2$ is in the direction of $x$ with magnitude $|x|^3$. Since every nonnegative real magnitude can be attained by $|x|^3$ as $|x|$ ranges across $[0,\infty)$, and every possible direction can be attained by changing the direction of $x$, it is clear that $f$ must be surjective.

In other words, let $\hat{x}=x/|x|$ so that $x=|x|\hat{x}$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^n$. Then $f(x)=y$ if and only if $|x|^3\hat{x}=|y|\hat{y}$, so given any such $y$ we can always pick $|x|=|y|^{1/3}$ and $\hat{x}=\hat{y}$ to ensure $f(x)=y$. So given any $y$, we have found $x$ so that $f(x)=y$, so $f$ is surjective.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually it’s a true or false question. I wrongly concluded that the function is not surjective and posted the problem wrong. Sorry for the mistake. Thank you once again for the correct answer.

Comment: @LawrenceMano If you are satisfied with the answer you could conisder upvoting/approving it.